# Adding an element to the DOM with Chrome developer tooling?

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to add add an element to the DOM with Chrome developer tooling?  For example select a `div` element and then add another `div` sibling right after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 3 workflows for editing nodes as HTML:

- Select a node so that DevTools highlights it blue. Click the **More** [image: the **more icon] icon next to a node then select **Edit As HTML**. This icon only shows up next to the currently-selected node.
- Right-click any node (doesn't have to be the currently-selected one) then select **Edit As HTML**.
- Select the node you want to edit so that DevTools highlights it blue. Then press <kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>F2</kbd> (Windows, Linux).

To commit your changes:

- Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Windows, Linux).
- Click anywhere outside the **Edit As HTML** text box.

To discard:

- Press <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

Source for keyboard shortcuts: [Elements panel keyboard shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts#elements)

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.  We can click the three dots `(...)` next to an element we want to edit and select `Edit as HTML`, and proceed to modify the markup from there.

Added a screenshot below:
[image]